# how to enable export to csv in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am using out of the box ag-grid , is there a feature on it for exporting to excel. So far i have not written any event code to export to csv. I was thinking that just like it's sort and filter features this is also implemented out of the box (like the context menu of highcharts as an example).

So is there a grid option that I need to set to make it ready for exporting to to csv or excel

thanks

Answer (score 5):

The current version of ag-grid (4.0.7) does not have that feature. To accomplish the csv export you'll have to call ag-grid api functions, e.g.:

```
$scope.exportToCsv = function () {
    var params = {
        skipHeader: false,
        skipFooters: true,
        skipGroups: true,
        fileName: "export.csv"
    };
    $scope.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable the enterprise Excel export feature then there are two approaches depending on the AG Grid packages that you have installed.

**Packages**

If your package.json file looks like this then you are using the grid packages approach.

```json
"ag-grid-community": "^27.0.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^27.0.",
"ag-grid-angular": "^27.0.0",
```

Then all you need to include in your code is the following import to enable all the enterprise features.

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise'
```

**Modules**
If your package.json file looks like this you are using feature modules. You will need to include the `MenuModule` and `ExcelExportModule` to have the context menu with the Excel exports enabled.

```json
"@ag-grid-community/core": "^27.0.0",
"@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^27.0.",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/menu": "^27.0.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export": "^27.0.0",
```

You will also need to ensure that these modules are registered with the grid using the `ModuleRegistry`

```
import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model";
import { MenuModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/menu";
import { ExcelExportModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export";

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
    ClientSideRowModelModule,
    MenuModule,
    ExcelExportModule
]);
```

You can find the full details in the [docs](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/packages-modules/) or here is an [article](https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/) by AG Grid on using modules.

Answer (score 0):

To enable export simply in ag-grid(version 20 or greater than) in the context-menu by right clicking on a cell.
By default, the context menu provides the values 'copy' and 'paste'. Copy will copy the selected cells or rows to the clipboard. Paste will always, forever, be disabled.

For Angular 2 and above versions use this

```
import { AllModules } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules'; /* Import AllModules */

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [modules]="modules"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){

  }
  public modules: Module[] = AllModules;/*This variable Enable Export in context Menu*/

}
```

Reference :- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/